# Which fork is more active, English Wikitravel or English Wikivoyage?

Tags: online-resources

Which fork is more active (in terms of genuine contributions, not spam or vandalism): the English language Wikitravel, or the English language Wikivoyage?

I noticed that [Wikitravel](http://wikitravel.org/en/Ulaanbaatar#Buy) had some info on ATMs in Ulaanbaatar that [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Ulaanbaatar#How_to_get_cash) didn't have, and it seemed Wikitravel had more of an edit history than Wikivoyage.

Wikivoyage has a page which [compares the two](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wikivoyage:Wikivoyage_and_Wikitravel#Differences), but it's comparing current data for WikiVoyage to February 2016 data for Wikitravel.

Comment: Isn't "fork" a technical form for travel.se? How about using a less technical word? Site for example.

Comment: @Heidel Ber Gensis It's the correct word to use here: both sites originate from the same content.

Comment: Related: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/881/wikitravel-vs-wikivoyage-whats-going-to-be-the-difference

Comment: @jpatokal true, it's the correct word, but in a technical context. For a normal traveler it might be confusing.

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis we aren't normal. :) Most of us also have accounts on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Ok boss, it's just a suggestion but I think making questions more travel-friendly is better.. For most people they are just "two sites". Not a fork..

Comment: @HeidelBerGensis: The fact that one of the sites is a fork of the other is, however, pretty important for making sense of the question. The question would not be as understandable if this information was not present there.

Comment: Looks like Wikitravel are hiding their [Special:Statistics](http://wikitravel.org/en/Special:Statistics) page, so it can't be easily compared. You can check the recent changes pages for both. Wikivoyage seems to have a lot more edits over the last few days anyway.

Comment: Voting to leave open! Who voted to close this? Please explain, I find it's a great question and looking forward to a good answer. When using those travel resources I am always wondering which one to consult or link here on TSE as a source.

Comment: was this meant to be on META ?

Comment: @joeblow no, it's a question about online resources, not a question about travel.se.

Comment: Andrew -= fair enough!

Comment: How would you define more active?

Comment: This should be migrated to Meta. As of now there's now clear contender to the title, so it's impossible to say with certainty.

Comment: @JonathanReez can you explain why it's a meta question?

Comment: We've previously had a Meta question on a similar topic: http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/881/wikitravel-vs-wikivoyage-whats-going-to-be-the-difference. Meta would allow a biased discussion with personal opinion, rather than something verifiable.

Comment: @JonathanReez to be fair, that other question you link to was mine, and it still grates on me that it's on meta, it should totally be on the main site :)

Answer (score 6):

Wikivoyage.

[Source](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Wikivoyage:Wikivoyage_and_Wikitravel#Differences) (which I know you've already cited), but I've done the maths.

Since the Wikivoyage total is 'live' and the Wikitravel total is Feb, we'll have to make some assumptions, but I believe them to be valid.

Let's take the Wikitravel first.  13 years and 1 month, assuming the start of 2013.  2,541,627 over that time = 194,264ish edits a year.

Wikivoyage = 3,020,088, divided by 13 years and 6.5 months = 223,021ish edits a year.

So based on that, Wikivoyage wins.

However, this is kinda moot, as Wikitravel only launched, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikivoyage#Launch) in 2004, and Wikivoyage in 2007.  So the numbers seem a bit strange to me.

What I'd focus on instead is the Alexa rank, which while Wikitravel is ranked higher, [Wikitravel has slipped](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikivoyage#Evolution) from 3000th to 6000th in the past few years and continues to slip as people move to the wikivoyage. That's my feeling anyway, and while it's still more 'ranked' and familiar to people (friends often mention wikitravel, never wikivoyage) the editing community certainly seems to prefer wikivoyage.

Comment: You can find the current Alex rankings for [Wikitravel here](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/wikitravel.org) and [for Wikivoyage here](http://www.alexa.com/siteinfo/wikivoyage.org). Interestingly Wikivoyage is on a 5k rank in Germany where sensibility for open-source is high.

Comment: This depends on whether WV keeps the edits it had from WT before the fork.